# Bing and Esri Satellite basemaps are misaligned by about 2 meters

Tags: coordinate-system, overlay, basemap, bing-maps, arcgis-online-basemaps

Did you ever notice a shift (2 meters) between satellite basemaps from Bing and Esri?

[image: basemap_shift_animated]

The problem basically arose when GIS technicians have to deal with drawings made in CAD using Bing basemaps as reference that do not overlap properly with the Esri basemaps.

And this is particularly important when one wants to share a map through ArcGIS Online, which obviously uses Esri basemaps (I know it is possible to use Bing maps with ArcGIS Online, but this is not the point).

As far as I know, both basemaps have the same Web Mercator reference system.

Is there any way to deal with this other than shifting the whole data by a delta x, y in your opinion?

Comment: Your red arrow point to the corner of the roof which is wrong because images are ortorectified to the ground level. At ground level those two images seem to align pretty well but a few meters differences in georeferencing of satellite images are normal.

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, looking at other features at the ground (e.g. sidewalks) there still is a considerable (i.e. in the order of 1-2 m) shift, as you also noticed. As both images come from the same vendor (DigitalGlobe, as I can see from the references), I thought the images would match better regardless the different versions. Still, this seems to be an issue for those who works at large scale (e.g. 1:500). I guess the best would be to be consistent with the use of the same basemaps, but this is not always possible when data creation involves many different workers and thus softwares.

Comment: Imagine yourself making a map about something that you look at 600 km distance and perhaps 1-2 meters does not feel so much. By the specifications of the instrument the accuracy at 90% confidence level is 5 meters https://dg-cms-uploads-production.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/document/file/196/DG2017_WorldView-4_DS.pdf. If you need sub-meter accuracy you must use other source data and be prepared to pay for that.

Comment: I completely agree with your point. Thanks for making things clear. I would always stress that, when possible, using the same image reference across multiple platforms would be the right way to go.